# The restrictiveness of assumptions

Tags: soft-question, terminology

Sometimes we can make assumptions without loss of generality. Sometime we restrict the problem a lot, sometimes just a little - it is with hardly any loss of generality. What is the jargon for the later two? "restrictive assumption" and "soft assumption"?

I'll give an example:

> To rectify this, we make $\mathbb D$ a bounded subset $\mathbb D\subset\mathbb  R$, which is a .... assumption.

I want to say that it important to make this assumption for mathematical reasons, but does not make much difference for the results (because we can still make $\mathbb D$ as large as we need).

Comment: Why not say just what you said? State the assumption, and then justify it.

Comment: @quasi: I don't have the space in my publication - I have to fight for every word, while shortening my text. In fact the real explanation would be quite a bit longer than what I wrote here. It was just an example. But the expert reader should be able to see that the assumption is "soft" at a glance as well. But I need to say it at least, so I need the adjective.

Comment: Clarity is the key. What you said was clear. Trying to save a sentence or two at the expense of clarity is, in my opinion, not the right choice.

Comment: @quasi: in fact, the long explanation is not necessary, because I can simply quote a reference ;-)

Comment: Sure, then say something like: As noted in [ref], it suffices to consider the case ...

Comment: @quasi: Check out my answer.

Comment: I'd just say you were considering a slightly restrictive special case, something like that.  Brevity should never be allowed to confuse things.

Answer (score 1):

I think the terms are "weak assumption" for a non-restrictive assumption close to "without loss of generality" and "strong assumption" for restrictive assumptions.

Comment: "weak assumption", "strong assumption"? How well known are those terms?

Comment: @quasi I would say quite well known - I've definitely seen them lots of times. Anyways, it's clear what they mean: a weak assumption doesn't let you do much new (so is close to WLOG, which doesn't let you do *anything* new), while a strong assumption lets you do a lot new. So this matches what "weak" and "strong" mean in natural language in the first place.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Interesting way of looking at it. You are right of course. I would have looked at it from another perspective: "weak assumption" is good, because it keeps the method general and makes sure it is applicable to many situations. But yeah, the point is often to restrict the number of applicable situations, in order to be able to do more in these - (which is specialization).